# Google sheets protect cells in range once filled

Tags: google-sheets

I'm running a Super Bowl squares contest and I created a Google sheet where people can buy a square by entering their own name (check [here](https://www.superbowlsquares.org/how-to-play) if you don't know how this game works).

What I'm trying to do is protect the grid of squares (10 x 10 grid) to only allow users to enter information (their name) in a blank square.  Once they enter their name, I want the cell to automatically be protected to nobody else can overwrite it.

Is there a way to set this up in Google sheets?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your tags of question, only ``google-sheets`` is added. For example, I think that your question can be resolved using Google Apps Script. How about using a script?

Comment: Is there anything that we can do for your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google Apps Script and installable on edit or on change trigger.